# Can a grouping variable also be a predictor or vice versa

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I sometimes see that a grouping variable such as `study` ($1,2,...15$) is used as a grouping variable to the **right** of the `|`:

`metafor::rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ 1 | district/study, data=dat)` (see [HERE](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011#three-level_model))

But sometimes that same previously grouping variable `study` is used as a varying random slope to the **left** of the `|`:

`metafor::res.mv <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ factor(study) | district, data=dat)` (see [HERE](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011#multivariate_parameterization_of_the_model))

**Questions**

1- Does the use of a grouping variable to the **right** vs. **left** of the `|` lead to different models?

2- Suppose our grouping variable was `gender` (with 2-levels), then, I assume using `gender` as a grouping variable to the **right** of the `|` won't make much sense, correct?

3- I sometimes hear that if a grouping variable (e.g., school) has a small sample size (e.g., only 3 schools in the data), then we can use that grouping variable as a predictor instead of a grouping variable, is this reasonable?